# Visually see flap settings from passenger window behind wing

Tags: aircraft-design, airbus, flaps

I've flown on a lot of Airbus and seen a lot of trip reports on YT and wonder if you can visually see the different flap settings (if you are seated at a window behind the wing), for example Up, Flap 1, Flap 1+f, Flap 2 and FULL.

Comment: I have experienced sitting at such place in different premium and low cost airlines. And I never looked something like this. So, I think this is not a very common things and could only be an airline's preference to make it easy for the aircraft mechanics and engineers.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you can definitely tell how much the flaps are deployed just by looking at the numbers on the flap itself, close to the root of the wing, which gives the angle in degrees ([original picture](https://www.airliners.net/photo/LAN-Peru/Airbus-A320-233/291305/L)):

[image: A320 wing]

I've personally seen it on many A320 but I can't tell if it's a universal thing, I'm quite sure I've never seen it on a B737 for example.

Comment: Though unless I'm terribly unobservant, I don't recall ever seeing this sort of stenciling/printing on any of the flaps I've observed on my many flights.  So I don't think this is a universal answer.

Comment: @Milwrdfan: I've personally seen it on many A320. If it's a universal thing I can't tell, I'm quite sure I've never seen it on a B737 for example. I'm going to update my answer, thanks for your comment

Comment: See also: https://www.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/wcikbe/what_are_these_numbers_found_on_an_airbusa320/

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: A couple pilots in that thread [say](https://www.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/wcikbe/what_are_these_numbers_found_on_an_airbusa320/iicvgcl/) they're for maintenance after any work on the flaps, and for a pilot to check in case of indicator failure in the cockpit.  Makes sense.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I don't think a pilot can see those markings from the cockpit. But a flight attendant can for sure.

Comment: @sophit: Correct. But on [a thread of that reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/wcikbe/what_are_these_numbers_found_on_an_airbusa320/iicvgcl/), two users who I think are pilots say that cabin crew aren't trained to read those markings, so in the event of an indicator failure, one of the pilots would get up and walk back to have a look to verify their flaps state because that's safety-critical.

Comment: @PeterCordes: ah ok, that makes sense  It would be nice to know if there are some regulations about those markings.